# Can some one explain my about the return type int __attribute__((weak))?

Tags: c

In [linux source code](https://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx/blob/master/kernel/fork.c) I found the following:

```
int __attribute__((weak)) arch_dup_task_struct(struct task_struct *dst,
                           struct task_struct *src)
{
    *dst = *src;
    return 0;
}
```

Can some one explain my about the return type  `int __attribute__((weak))`?

Comment: Have you read the gcc documentation? Is there a specific question you have?

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I did not know it is related to gcc. And why should it be? Is gcc part of linux ?

Comment: Well, Linux [kind of requires](https://www.kernel.org/doc/linux/README) gcc.

Answer (score 3):

This is linker attribute specific to GCC. It makes the `arch_dup_task_struct` function *weak* linker symbol. It means that the definition will be used unless somewhere in the linker input there is a function of the same name without the attribute (i.e. strong) - then the strong function will be used.

The attribute is useful for library functions which may be easily overridden. The library provides default implementation, and the user of the library may provide own implementation which will replace the library one.

Comment: can we say it is function overloading in C++?

Comment: No it has nothing to do with C++ function overloading, which is about having several function definitions for different combination of arguments. C++ overloading is not about replacing a function with another.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute is not part of the type. It is a GCC extension attribute that tells the compiler to make `arch_dup_task_struct` a [weak symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol).